# Pattern matching - variable in scope outside if-block

Tags: c#, pattern-matching, c#-7.0

I'm trying to understand why `y` is in scope in the following example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int x = 1;
    if (x is int y) { }

    Console.WriteLine("This should NOT be in scope:" + y); // but it is...
}
```

If I change `int x` to `object x`, then `y` is no longer in scope (as expected).

Why is `y` in scope when the expression being matched is of `int` type and not when the type is `object`? It's odd that the scoping changes based on the expression type.

`y` seems to stay in scope when the expression type and the pattern type are the same, and they're both *value types*. (Same issue exists when both types are `DateTime`, but doesn't exist when they're both `string`).

(csc version is 2.0.0.61213.)

---

**Update:** It looks like `y` is in scope in both cases. In the `object` case, the compiler error is "Use of unassigned local variable 'y'."  So it's not complaining about the variable being out of scope.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/features/patterns/docs/features/patterns.md#scope-of-pattern-variables) can throw some light upon it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pattern match variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680781/pattern-match-variable-scope)

Comment: It is by design ^

Comment: @PatrickHofman so if I understand this correctly, the `int` behavior (`y` being in scope) is correct. And `object` behavior is _incorrect_ and should be fixed at a later release. Is that right?

Comment: @ErenErsönmez, sadly the language team disagree with you. They believe that leaking `y` into the surrounding scope, even when unusable, is a good design decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the output code created, which results in this strange behavior, which is a bug in my opinion. I guess this will be fixed eventually.

The thing is this: `x is int y` evaluates to `true` *on compile time*, resulting in the `if` rendered obsolete and the assignment done before the `if`. [See the compiled code here](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbFK5MmANwHswATGAFkqkABQoATpCgBtALowqkqCACU2FjG0xIyGAA8YAXhgBGHDt0AzGGKNg6emAjXMYAX2zYr9HhBAeIlQAOgB1aTQAGUhUMQAiABUAC0cYEGSeYCJBADkAeUSYAlRdCHTSHlxUAC54mABqFzVMGAB6NuLgfTAekBCB7C8PIA==):

```
int num = 1;
int num2 = num;
bool flag = true;
if (flag)
{
}
Console.WriteLine("This should NOT be in scope:" + num2);
```

There seems a bug in the compilation of the `is object` variant. It compiles to something like this (note the parenthesis I added):

```
int num = 1;
object arg;
bool flag = (arg = num as object) != null;

Console.WriteLine("This should NOT be in scope:" + arg);
```

Which is valid, even in C# 6. However, the compiler thinks `arg` isn't always set. Adding an `else` branch fixes this bug:

```
else { y = null; }
```

[Results in](https://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#b:master/K4Zwlgdg5gBAygTxAFwKYFsDcAoADsAIwBswBjGUogQxBBgGEYBvbFK5MmANwHswATGAFkqkABQoATpCgBtALowqkqCACU2FjG0xIyGAA8YAXhgBGHDt0AzGGKNg6PAgCtUpfQjXMYAXxioRCCoPggmMBDARESYftjYVvQ8ECA8RKgAdADq0mgAMpCoYgBEACoAFo4wIOU8UYIAcgDypTAEIZDVpDy4qABcxTAA1DBesQD0423A+mCzIBmL2L7LQA===):

```
int num = 1;
object arg;
bool flag = arg = num as object != null;
if (!flag)
{
    arg = null;
}
Console.WriteLine("This should NOT be in scope:" + arg);
```

Comment: You're right. As I added an update in the question, the compiler was complaining about an unassigned variable, not about name not existing in the current context. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

That's is something I had found in VS15P4 (or P5) and it was being tracked on GitHub:

[Definite assignment versus pattern-matching when pattern always matches #14651](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/14651)

Putting aside all the discussions, it is a scoping issue which occurs when the pattern *always* matches, as the title suggests.

I thought it was fixed before RC so I haven't actually tested afterwards but it seems the issue still persists.

Let's see if it will be fixed in the actual release, which is tomorrow :)

Comment: Thanks, interesting info. But I don't understand how the change @gafter proposed relates to your question. His change basically relates to the _false_ branch of your if statement (which wasn't what you asked about).

Comment: It's not directly related. Just as you were, I was curious about the different behavior and asked about it. That probably made @gafter realize that there's an issue when the pattern always matches, so he raised an issue.