# c# how to 'return if not null' in a one liner?

Tags: c#

Is there a one liner to return something if it not null or continue execution, or how to make such thing?
All this to avoid copy pasta the IF lines in several methods.

Initial code would be this:

```
var error = ValidateStuff(someArg);
if (error != null)
{
    return error;
}
DoOtherStuff();
```

So how to refactor it in order to avoid copy pasting that same if everywhere?
Pseudo code would be something like

```
ValidateStuff(someArg) ? return ___ : continue;
DoSomethingElse();
AndMoreStuff();
```

-EDIT-
An even more simplistic example, in order to clear some doubts going on in some answers and comments:

```
public string Foo(string arg)
{
    string fuu = GetMeSomething(arg);

    if(fuu != null) return fuu;

    ImDoingThings();

    return "I did things";
}
```

Would be awesome to have this:

```
public string Foo(string arg)
{
    ReturnIfNotNull(GetMeSomething(arg));

    ImDoingThings();

    return "I did things.";
}
```

Comment: What is the bigger scope of this function? Do you have different classes that have a validate and then do stuff? Do they have a common purpose behind them?

Comment: You can't, all you can do to minimalise the code is omit the curly braces surrounding your return statement.

Comment: If you mostly expect valid input, you can make `EnsureStuffValid(someArg)` return nothing and throw an exception if stuff is not valid.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend switching to the standard error returning mechanism provided in C# - exceptions. They don't have to be manually propagated back up the call stack, which is what you essentially seem to be doing here.

Comment: You can make `ValidateStuff` return a `boolean` (`false` if Validation fails). You could then return the Validation Errors through an `out` or `ref` parameter, rather than as the function's return value. `string errors; If (!ValidateStuff(out errors)) { return errors; }`

Answer (score 12):

Sure:

```
void ValidateStuff(someArg) { 
    if (!validation(someArg)) { 
        throw new ValidationException("Whatever went wrong...", errorDetails);
    }
}
```

And in your code:

```
ValidateStuff(someArg);
DoOtherStuff();
```

P.S.: I often combine generic code in `ValidateStuff` with `#if (DEBUG) [...] #else [...] #endif`, so that production irrelevant stuff doesn't end up in production binaries.

---

What about warnings?

I use a few tricks for that:

1. Build an error object only if you really need it.
2. Similarly, build the list of errors only when something fails.
3. Make use of 'using' for easy coding. I'm a lazy coder... This is a small risk though; if you forget to use using, you're in trouble... Still, I think this risk is better than the alternative of "let's go on with the show and forget there was something warning in the first place".
4. If you have a better handler for your warnings (so: instead of the exception), use it and be done with it.
5. If an error occurs, throw the lot.

Obviously you can extend it as you see fit...

Without further due:

```
public class WarningsHandler : IDisposable
{
    private List<WarningErrorBase> errors = null;

    // Default handler. Remember to use 'using', or otherwise you'll end up 
    // with pain and suffering!
    public void Dispose()
    {
        var errors = FetchValidationResults();

        if (errors != null && errors.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(errors);
        }
    }

    // Handler if you have a better idea than using an Exception
    public IEnumerable<Error> FetchValidationResults() 
    {
        var errors = this.errors;
        this.errors = null;
        return errors;
    }

    public void Warn(bool condition, Func<Warning> errorBuilder)
    {
        if (condition) 
        { 
            if (errors == null) { errors = new List<WarningErrorBase>(); }
            errors.Add(errorBuilder()); 
        }
    }

    public void Error(bool condition, Func<Error> errorBuilder)
    {
        if (condition) 
        { 
            if (errors == null) { errors = new List<WarningErrorBase>(); }
            errors.Add(errorBuilder()); 

            throw new ValidationException(FetchValidationResults());
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it?

```
void MyThing()
{
    using (var handler = new WarningsHandler())
    {
        handler.Error(foo == null, "Foo must have a value");
        handler.Warn(foo.Count > 2, () => new Warning("You should have less than 2 foo's present.");
        // etc.
    }
}
```

---

Okay, just one more trick. :-)

A last way to mix different error messages with little overhead is to use `yield return`. This enables you to return multiple result values with different behaviors. Null values can be ignored trivially.

First we need a whole bunch of wrappers for this:

```
// We need some base interface that we can use for return values
public interface IResult { }

// We have to wrap normal return values
public class Result<T> : IResult
{
    public Result(T result) { this.Value = result; }

    public T Value { get; private set; }
}

// A few classes for messages, errors, warnings, ...
public class Message : IResult
{
    public Message(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        this.Text = string.Format(format, args);
    }

    public string Text { get; private set; }

    internal virtual void Handle(List<Message> messages)
    {
        messages.Add(this);
    }
}

public class Error : Message
{
    public Error(Exception ex) :
        base("Uncaught exception: {0}", ex.Message)
    { }

    public Error(string format, params object[] args) : 
        base(format, args)
    { }

    internal override void Handle(List<Message> messages)
    {
        throw new ValidationException(this.Text);
    }
}

// Other wrappers like warnings, etc. 
// Wrapping IEnumerable<IResult> is useful too.
```

Next, we need some helper method to execute our methods that now return an IEnumerable instead of a normal type. For that, I add a helper class, which basically handles the execution, unwrapping and return values.

```
public static class ExecutionEngine
{
    public static T Execute<T>(this IEnumerable<IResult> method)
    {
        List<Message> messages = new List<Message>();
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in method)
            {
                // yield return null is ignored here:
                if (item != null)
                {
                    // Handle validation results, messages, etc
                    Message msg = item as Message;
                    if (msg != null)
                    {
                        msg.Handle(messages);
                    }

                    Result<T> returnValue = item as Result<T>;
                    if (returnValue != null)
                    {
                        return returnValue.Value;
                    }

                    // handle other things, error if something's wrong
                }
            }

            throw new Exception("Method finished without a return value.");
        }
        catch (ValidationException)
        {
            // TODO: handle messages?

            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // TODO: handle messages?

            var error = new Error(ex);
            error.Handle(messages);

            throw; // unreachable because Error throws. This is to make sure it all compiles
        }
    }
}
```

Once we have all that in order, the code itself becomes pretty simple, and resembles a lot like you would do normally. The main difference is that you simply add 'yield return' everywhere, sometimes with an additional wrapper:

```
public IEnumerable<IResult> MyMethod()
{
    // Delegate validation to somewhere else. You might wrap an IEnumerable<IResult> here:
    yield return ValidateStuff(someArg);

    // Information messages, etc
    yield return new Message("Hello world!");

    // You might end up with an Exception you didn't expect...
    var tmp = new List<int>();
    tmp[2] = 2; // oopz...

    // ...
    yield return new Result<int>(12); // return 12;
}
```

The only thing remains is that you cannot call `MyMethod` anymore. This is easily fixed by using the execution engine:

```
int result = MyMethod().Execute<int>();
```

Comment: Wait, I thought that raising an exception when it could be avoided in C# was a good idea.

I would actually say that the OPs version is better, but that's why I'm asking what is your take on that.  That is specfically when it's something that can be recovered from.  In this case his list of errors.

Comment: @thinklarge only when the code can recover from the error in a meaningful way. Otherwise, returning an error object instead of throwing an exception is never a good idea.

Comment: @thinklarge Exceptions are there for stuff that needs exceptions. Throwing exceptions is just relatively slow in C#, which is why things like `int.TryParse` have been introduced. Still, I wouldn't avoid them. So in the case of validation lists, I'd defer the `throw` to a point where I would have done all the validations (add it to a list, then throw the whole list at once).

Comment: @atlaste Ok so my understanding was correct.  That's something that your answer assumes about the OPs post (granted it's a validation soooo not a bad assumption) but if he can recover above this point then wouldn't returning an error as he does be a better solution? We do something in our code similar to this with critical errors but we also issue warnings.  We also want to give the user ALL of the errors on a return so they can address them all at the same time.  So we infrequently throw exceptions unless it's something our code looks at and says nope, big old nope I can't handle that.

Comment: @thinklarge Ah, warnings. Here you go. [added to answer]

Comment: The assumption was correct, assuming it was an "exception" would be too restricting. I only gave an example after all. In a practical case we would want to return something, being it an error, warning, message, whatever. When i asked the question I was looking for a replacement of the "if not null -> return" so that it could be used in many cases, validation is just a scenario where it could be used. Never the less the answer is good even tho it focuses on the validation itself and not so much the question of avoiding the if lines still present in the answer.

Comment: @GothamLlianen I added another possible way to go to the answer that goes in the other direction: returning null simply has no effect anymore, which is the closest I can get to your question.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're likely going about this in the wrong way; you're probably going to be much better off `throw`ing exceptions rather than trying to return error codes.

But ... you can make something like your pseudo-code work using lambdas.  It gets messy (and would be even messier with generics), but for completeness and answering your *specific* question:

```
static Error ReturnIf(Error error,
    Func<Error, bool> predicate,
    Func<Error> rest)
{
    return predicate(error) ? error : rest();
}

static Error Test2(bool someArg)
{
    return ReturnIf(ValidateStuff(someArg), error => error != null, () =>
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
        AndMoreStuff();
        return null;
    });
}
```

Or, since you've actually said "return if not null", the code an be simplified and more specific:

```
static Error ReturnIfNotNull(Error error,
       Func<Error> rest)
{
    return error ?? rest();
}

static Error Test2(bool someArg)
{
    return ReturnIfNotNull(ValidateStuff(someArg) () =>
    {
        DoSomethingElse();
        AndMoreStuff();
        return null;
    });
}
```

I'm not suggesting you would actually want to *use* code such as this in your particular situation ... Although [Bart de Smet](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart) explored this technique extensively.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to validate is throw an custom exception.
(CustomException is my own class that inherited from Exception class)

for example,
I use this in my business layer: (save model in database or something else)

```
public class SomeService
{

    public void DoSomething(some params or some instance of a model class)
    {
        Validate(some params or an instance of a model class);

        // some other codes such as save data in database or etc ...

    }

    private void Validate(some params or an instance of a model class)
    {
        if(something is wrong)
            throw new CustomException("X is invalid"); // X is the name of wrong param
    }

}
```

and in presentation layer:

```
try
{
   var model = new someModel{ fill properties of model };

   var service = new SomeService();
   service.DoSomething(model);

   DoOtherStuff();
}
catch(CustomException ex)
{
  ShowMessageToUser(ex.Message);
}
```

Note: I catch just my custom exceptions, not business exceptions.

It's my dear war for validate parameters and models

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In newer C# versions, you can use [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#null-checks) for this. Instead of

```
var error = ValidateStuff(someArg);
if (error != null)
{
    return error;
}
```

you can write:

```
if (ValidateStuff(someArg) is var error)
{
    return error;
}
```

which can, if you want, be condensed into a single line:

```
if (ValidateStuff(someArg) is var error) return error;
```

(Note though that, unfortunately, `error`'s scope [extends beyond the `if` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40680781/87698).)