# C# 7.0 pattern matching variables' scope and assignment syntax

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Pre: [Pattern match variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40680781/pattern-match-variable-scope), but I'd like to know more about the assignment behavior.

I have done the following test.

In F1, it seems `i` is in the scope but not assigned, which I can understand it by F2.

But the situation in F3 makes me really puzzled because it can't be explained by F2.

Then in F4 it shows `!` has no effects in this situation.

```cs
// inside a class
object o = 1;
void F0() { // normal usage
    if(o is int i)
        WriteLine(i);
}
void F1() {
    if (o is int i)
        WriteLine(i);
    else
        WriteLine(i); // Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
    WriteLine(i); // the same as above
}
void F2() {
    int i;
    if (o is int) {
        i = (int)o; // just for simulation because 'as' can't unbox
        WriteLine(i);
    }
    else
        WriteLine(i); // Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
    WriteLine(i); // Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
}
void F3() {
    if (!(o is int i))
        WriteLine(i); // Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
    else
        WriteLine(i); // compile
    WriteLine(i); // Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
}
void F4() {
    _ = !(o is int i);
    Console.WriteLine(i); // Use of unassigned local variable 'i'

    _ = o is int i;
    Console.WriteLine(i); // Use of unassigned local variable 'i'
}
```

I can only conclude that this syntax treats `if` differently, that if `if condition` is true, it would assign inside `if true`'s scope, otherwise it would assign in the `if else`'s scope.

Is my understanding correct?(I guess not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets look closer at following statement:

```
o is int i
```

If `o` can be casted to `int` type this statement will return `true` and `i` variable will be set. If not, it will return `false` and `i` variable won't be initialized. Also, using such code in if statements moves variable to outer scope.

Lets go through your methods:

```
void F1() {
   if (o is int i)
        WriteLine(i);  // i was initialized, because o is int i returned true
    else
        WriteLine(i); // i was NOT initialized, so you have using of unassigned local variable 'i' here
    WriteLine(i); // the same as above, because i wasn't initialized in all code paths before this statement
}

void F2() {
    int i;
    if (o is int) {
        i = (int)o; // just for simulation because 'as' can't unbox
        WriteLine(i); // i was initialized in previous line
    }
    else
        WriteLine(i); // o is not int, so i wasn't initialized => using of unassigned local variable 'i'
    WriteLine(i); // i wasn't initialized in all code paths, using of unassigned local variable 'i'
}

void F3() {
    if (!(o is int i))
        WriteLine(i); // Using of unassigned local variable 'i' because o can't be casted to int => !(o is int i)
    else
        WriteLine(i); // compile - i was initialized
    WriteLine(i); // you wrote this statement can be compiled, in fact not, because i is not initialized in all code paths
}

void F4() {
    _ = (!(o is int i));
     Console.WriteLine(i); // Use of unassigned local variable 'i', because in case of unsuccessful casting i won't be intialized.
}
```

Comment: The last statement in F3 is not compiled indeed. It's because I caused the formal error so the compiler hide the latter one. I've edit my examples.

Comment: And in F4 I think the explanation should also be "i is not initialized in all code paths" because the new case I added in F4.

Comment: Yeah, in updated `F4` in case of unsuccessful casting you will have `i` not initialized before printing, so you should initialize it in all code paths to make it compileable. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

From the [spec for patterns in C# 7.0](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.0/pattern-matching.md#scope-of-pattern-variables):

> #### Scope of pattern variables
>
> The scope of a variable declared in a pattern is as follows:
>
> - If the pattern is a case label, then the scope of the variable is the *case block*.
>
> Otherwise the variable is declared in an *is_pattern* expression, and its scope is based on the construct immediately enclosing the expression containing the *is_pattern* expression as follows:
>
> - If the expression is in an expression-bodied lambda, its scope is the body of the lambda.
> - If the expression is in an expression-bodied method or property, its scope is the body of the method or property.
> - If the expression is in a `when` clause of a `catch` clause, its scope is that `catch` clause.
> - If the expression is in an *iteration_statement*, its scope is just that statement.
> - Otherwise if the expression is in some other statement form, its scope is the scope containing the statement.
>
> For the purpose of determining the scope, an *embedded_statement* is considered to be in its own scope. For example, the grammar for an *if_statement* is
>
> ```
> if_statement
>     : 'if' '(' boolean_expression ')' embedded_statement
>     | 'if' '(' boolean_expression ')' embedded_statement 'else' embedded_statement
>     ;
> ```
>
> So if the controlled statement of an *if_statement* declares a pattern variable, its scope is restricted to that *embedded_statement*:
>
> ```cs
> if (x) M(y is var z);
> ```
>
> In this case the scope of `z` is the embedded statement `M(y is var z);`.
>
> Other cases are errors for other reasons (e.g. in a parameter's default value or an attribute, both of which are an error because those contexts require a constant expression).
>
> > In C# 7.3 we added the following contexts in which a pattern variable may be declared:
> >     - If the expression is in a *constructor initializer*, its scope is the *constructor initializer* and the constructor's body.
> >     - If the expression is in a field initializer, its scope is the *equals_value_clause* in which it appears.
> >     - If the expression is in a query clause that is specified to be translated into the body of a lambda, its scope is just that expression.

Comment: I searched 'assign' just now and found the first part indeed talks about assignment. It says 'the variable is assigned after the is operator is true', but according my test it is actually determined by the entire *if_condition*

Comment: Looking at `F1` and `F3` in your examples, they are both compatible with the spec.
The logic analyzing `is` has an understanding of which of the two branches has an assigned/unassigned variable, and the `if` just knows that the true branch goes into the first block and the false branch goes into the `else` block. The `if` doesn't have any logic of its own for assignment.